# Unable to add element to ICollection of Model Class or update the foreign key in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So I created two model classes for my web API. The buyers and Apartments Classes. A buyer can have multiple apartments. So My Model Classes are as follows:

```
public class Apartment
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int NbofRooms { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Buyer
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int Credit { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Apartment> apartments { get; set; }
    }
```

So the project created two tables in the database with the Apartments table containing BuyerID. So I have no idea if I want to create a purchase function given an Apartment ID and Buyer ID how to change the BuyerID in the database.
Here is my attempted method in the Buyers Controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}/{ApartmentID}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutBuyerApartment([FromRoute] int id, [FromRoute] int apartID, [FromBody] Buyer buyer)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != buyer.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var Apartments = await _context.Apartments.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == apartID);

            _context.Entry(Apartments).State = EntityState.Modified;
            buyer.apartments.Add(Apartments);
            _context.Entry(buyer).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BuyerExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

How should I change this one so that it works or is there any other way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach it's to tell EF their direct relationship on your model Apartments

```
public class Apartment
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int NbofRooms { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int BuyerId { get; set; } //Make it nullable if an aparment may not have a buyer at some point

        public Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
    }
```

This convention as the same impact in the database but by changing the Apartment buyers Id it will reflect on your buyers apartment list, plus adds the benefit to be able to access directly through the Apartment the Buyer's info

Comment: What would it make me change also in my project?

Comment: Nice! You can check the one-to-many relationship conventions here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx , if it helped you can mark this answer as accepted

Comment: But there is supposed to be a way without changing the database isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean? That solution has no impact on the database since your previous solution already generated those tables, This solution only adds more functionalities like including the buyers model from the apartment point of view and fixes your issue related with not being able to change it's buyer

Comment: Hello sir, the GET method started giving me net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK) error could it be from the changes? It does it just for the first GET method which returns all apartments.